# CSS Height - text doesnt fit

Tags: css

I'm having a problem getting my page to expand to display different length blogs.

I've read up on the other answers here and created a test page for now but it doesnt expand despite adding : min-height:625px;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 625px;
    overflow:hidden;
but its not working!

I'm using container on most pages, container-blog on the blog page (I've got round it for now by creating a really long page that everything fits on, but there must be a better way?   and container-test on my test page so i can play around with the settings without messing up the live page.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
#main-content {
  height: 440px;   <-- remove this
  padding: 20px 20px 10px 10px;
  width: 530px;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, its much better, but still truncating

Comment: All fixed now (my problem with text colour!)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the height from your #main-content declaration, your padding is also causing the content to be hidden which indicates an overflow hidden is coming into play.

Comment: Thank you so much!!  This is much better, although its still truncating some of my text

Comment: I have removed the overflow hidden and also the padding, but stil truncating?

Comment: All fixed now (my problem with text colour!)

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the height references and check if the overflow property is set the way you want it.

Comment: Thankyou.  I have changed the height (now css : main-content-test) and I have removed the overflow property incase this caused the truncating, but the text is still being cut about half way down.

Comment: All fixed now (my problem with text colour!)

Answer (score 0):

In your #main-content you are restricting the height to 440px. Remove that.